# How to getElement by tag, tag name, then click tag position (not working) // mirror iMacros program (working)

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

**Objective:** automatically run web reports, save to file, upload to FTP

**Problem:** cannot click the elements in VBA, but I know the route I need to take because the macro successfully works in the iMacros program (https://imacros.net/download/)

**Question:** how can I mirror iMacro command in VBA or what is the best way to write in VBA? I am excited to get the solution and thank you for taking the time to help me out!

**HTML:**

```
<frame name="leftFrame" src:"/client1-power/utility/CommonControllerServlet?action=folderAction&subaction=getRootFolders&folderId=null" frameBorder="0" marginHeight="0" noResize="noresize" scrolling="no">

<a title="Workspaces" class="leftnavleaflink" id="itemTextLink5" onmouseover="return true;" onclick="javascript:clickOnFolder("5");" oncontextmenu="showContextMenu("5");return false;" target="mainFrame" shape="">Workspaces</a>
```

**iMacros - Working :)**

```
VERSION BUILD=12.5.503.8802
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.00
URL GOTO=https://advantage.iriworldwide.com/client1-power/SplashLogin.jsp
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:j_username CONTENT=xxxxx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=NAME:j_password CONTENT=xxxxx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=NAME:submitButton
FRAME NAME=leftFrame
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Workspaces
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"My Workspaces"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:XP3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"Data for Interactive Edge"
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"Salty Snacks"
FRAME NAME=mainFrame
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"26 Weeks - Regions"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"13 Weeks - Regions"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"13 Weeks - Markets-Parent Company"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"52 Weeks - Regions"
```

**VBA Code - Not Working :(**

```
Sub iriAutomation()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://advantage.iriworldwide.com/client1-power/SplashLogin.jsp"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    objIE.document.getElementById("usrname").Value = "xxxxx"
    objIE.document.getElementById("password").Value = "xxxxx"
    objIE.document.getElementById("submitButton").Click
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    'objIE.document.getElementById("5").Click -----NOT WORKING
    'objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:clickOnFolder(""5"");" -----NOT WORKING
    'objIE.document.HTMLDocument.getElementsByTagName ("Workspaces") -----NOT WORKING
    'objIE.document.getElementById("itemTextLink5").Click -----NOT WORKING
    'objIE.document.getElementById("5").getElementsByTagName("a").click -----NOT WORKING
    'objIE.document.HTMLDocument.getElementsByName ("leftFrame") -----NOT WORKING
End Sub
```

***Run-time error '438':*** Object doesn't support this property or method

**For frame counting purposes:**
[image]

Comment: At what line do you get the run-time error? When you are given the warning, you can press « Debug » and it will bring you directly to the line of the error.

Comment: Thanks Charles! I get the error on ever line of code that says "-----NOT WORKING". I ran each line individuals just trying to click the "Workspaces" tab. I cannot get past that step. In the iMacro program, it first brings focus to the "FRAME NAME=leftFrame" then it clicks the tab.

Comment: How do I click any of the icons at https://www.att.com/ ?

Comment: Is that comment a new question?

Comment: Yes, that is essential what I am trying to do. How can I click something that is nested?

Comment: which icons are you referring to in that link?

Comment: Wireless. How can I click that icon in VBA?

Comment: Wireless isn't nested in a frame. It is simply .objIE.document.querySelector("[alt=Wireless]").Click

Comment: How can I focus the frame first? Then I should be able to click my tag name.

Comment: Can you show the html up to and including the closing frame tag? </frame>

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach for handling frames is to get the frame object then access the contentDocument within. For example, assuming the subitem you want is within frame 1:

```
objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("itemTextLink5").click
```

Using the name

```
objIE.document.getElementsByName("leftFrame")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("itemTextLink5").click
```

---

As seems you have framesets as parents you may need to descend them e.g.

```
objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(1).getElementsByTagName("frame")(1).contentDocument.getElementById("itemTextLink5").click
```

Comment: Thank you, but neither are working. I tried them both together too. Is it possible to go by tag ("frame") then name ("leftFrame")? What else could I try?

Comment: Please explain what not working means? Also, did you check which frame number your element is in?

Comment: How do I know what the frame number is?

Comment: you would open dev tools and click on the html, then Ctrl + F, put frame in the search box and hit enter. Then cycle through the matches. Remember indices start at 0

Comment: I have shown an edit where you can try navigating to the frame as well.

Comment: I updated the post with a picture of the frames, can you take a look and make sure I am in the right place?

Comment: you have two parent framesets you may have to handle. Did you try the ie.navigate method?

Comment: I did try, I've been at this all morning :) When navigating the URL, it force closes the web page. I am trying the debug.print method. If it prints, I should have my path.

Comment: Also, there is, which I think unlikely, objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(1).getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("itemTextLink5").click

Comment: Set x = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(1)
    Debug.Print x.ID
    objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(1).Click ---this is working, but how do I add the next level to the debugger? Also the above doesn't work.

Comment: Set x = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(1).getElementsByTagName("frame")(1)
    Debug.Print x.tagName ----this is working.... hmm, i hope this is it!

Comment: you've got the idea

Comment: objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(1).getElementsByTagName("frame")(1).contentDocument.getElementById("itemTextLink5").click

Comment: Hmm. Still not working. Can you check this out and let me know if its relevant to me? I have nested HTML code inside, after i open the frame, I cannot drill down further. https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/2wd6j1/vba_switch_focus_on_multiple_html_within_one_web/

Comment: That code isn't a great example. It is essentially looping all iframes to find an iframe with a partic id when in fact the iframe could just have been selected by id without the loop. It is not particularly relevant here as we have already established that you can't use the src of your frame as it causes the browser to close. You could try manually clicking on that link and checking the link that you actually end up at against what we discussed in my now deleted version  of an additional .Navigate2.

Comment: How could I get into the HTML inside the frame in the image attached to the post?

Comment: I think objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(1).getElementsByTagName("frame")(1).contentDocument

Comment: hope u got there

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to work with HTTP requests.

The following should get you logged in:

```
Sub iri()
Dim req As WinHttpRequest
Set req = New WinHttpRequest
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
set doc = New HTMLDocument
Dim reqBody As String
Dim userName As String
Dim pswd As String
userName = "user"
pswd = "12345"
reqBody = "j_username=" & userName & "&j_password=" & pswd & "&login-form-type=pwd&submitButton=Login"
With req
    .Open "POST", "https://advantage.iriworldwide.com/client1-power/SplashLogin.jsp", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send reqBody
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
End Sub
```

Once you are logged in you can manipulate the response HTML, which is stored in `doc`, however you please.
References used:

```
Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1

Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Awesome, I updated the UN & PW, no errors. Can I see what is processing? Can you give me an example of the next line of code? I just need something to get me started.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're looking for. The HTML page that appears in your browser after you log in, should now be stored in `doc`. If the data you are looking for is stored in that page you can parse `doc` as an HTML object and get the data. If there are more requests (aka clicks on buttons etc) that need to be made, then you should track them down and send them to the server and work with the responses you get. Try `debug.print` the response text for starters.